# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Area not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am creating an Area using ASP.NET MVC 3, by right clicking the project to add an Area called `MyArea`.

[image: Project screenshot]

Visual Studio 2010 automatically created the AreaRegistration and add RegisterAllAreas() to Application_Start() in Global.asax

But this URL doesn't work: http://localhost:1733/MyArea/AreaHome/Index

[image: Error message]

Even though the route seems to be registered.

[image: RouteDebugger]

Could anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question (I don't quite know how to read the route tester results) but does your AreaHome Controller have and Index action? (I followed the same steps and let visual studio do the registration and I'm able to access `MyArea/AreaHome/Index` )

Comment: Yes it has the Index action (thanks anyway). I used to build websites in MVC 2, but I am new to MVC 3 and Areas. So if you could do it, this is probably a problem with my Visual Studio or something...?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it with MVC2. Let me install try it with MVC3 and i'll give you an update.

Comment: Seems to work for me with MVC3 as well. I'd say, just create another MVC3 project and see if you run into the same thing again.

Comment: I've created another new project, same thing. But thanks anyway!

Comment: so, it looks like you have added a custom route. It seems like the default route should work fine (atleast for the examples you have posted). Can you try deleting the custom route or at least post the route that you have added ?

Comment: xixonia was right. I had to specify the namespace of the controller... perhaps it didn't work because I just copied the controller and view from the default ones. Thanks Bala!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the big things that trips me up when creating new areas is that the template does not automatically reference the new Controller namespaces. You can see what I mean in this similar post:

[Cannot load view in area in asp.net mvc 3 using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843720/cannot-load-view-in-area-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-vb-net/5843798#5843798)

It may be in VB.net, but the same solution can be applied.